# MySQL: optimize query for scoring calculation

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a data table that I use to do some calculations. The resulting data set after calculations looks like:

```
+------------+-----------+------+----------+
| id_process | id_region | type | result   |
+------------+-----------+------+----------+
|          1 |         4 |    1 |  65.2174 |
|          1 |         5 |    1 |  78.7419 |
|          1 |         6 |    1 |  95.2308 |
|          1 |         4 |    1 |  25.0000 |
|          1 |         7 |    1 | 100.0000 |
+------------+-----------+------+----------+
```

By other hand I have other table that contains a set of ranges that are used to classify the calculations results. The range tables looks like:

```
 +----------+--------------+---------+
 | id_level | start |  end |  status |
 +----------+--------------+---------+
 |        1 |   0   |   75 |  Danger |
 |        2 |  76   |   90 |  Alert  |
 |        3 |  91   |  100 |  Good   |
 +----------+--------------+---------+
```

I need to do a query that add the corresponding 'status' column to each value when do calculations. Currently, I can do that adding the following field to calculation query:

```
select
   ...,
   ...,
   [math formula] as result,
(select status 
   from ranges r
   where result between r.start and r.end) status
from ...
where ...
```

It works ok. But when I have a lot of rows (more than 200K), calculation query become slow.

My question is: there is some way to find that 'status' value without do that subquery?

Some one have worked on something similar before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for a subquery and join:

```
select s.*, r.status
from (select s.*
      from <your query here>
     ) s left outer join
     ranges r
     on s.result between r.start and r.end
```

Explicit `join`s often optimize better than nested `select`.  In this case, though, the `ranges` table seems pretty small, so this may not be the performance issue.